# Using different activity margins than those mentioned in Android design guidelines

Tags: android

is it OK to use different margins than the 16dp margins mentioned in the android design guidelines? would it affect the design? what are some of the other recommended values? multiples of 8dp ?

Comment: they are "Recommended" guide lines, that does not mean you have to follow them to the T

Comment: Do whatever looks fine for your app. In general, the default paddings and margins look good on most devices and add a familiar look since users are already used to them but if you think you can do better things with the given real-estate, feel free to use smaller values.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you can use different activity margins. The original are just recommended, you can customize your own from the xml, and see what it looks like in the Preview/Design page.